# How can I make gnome-tweaks changes apply to a newly plugged in USB keyboard without going through the GUI?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, gnome-tweaks

I use `gnome-tweaks` to turn my Caps Lock into a Control Key. This works normally, but not when I plug in a new external keyboard. I can make it work by:

1. Opening `gnome-tweaks`
2. Getting to the right place on the GUI: Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Caps Lock behaviour
3. Flipping between any other option and "Caps Lock is also a Ctrl"

Is there some terminal command I can run that will refresh `gnome-tweaks` for my currently plugged in devices? Failing that, is there a command I can run that will do this switch I'm currently doing manually?

This is [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1899206), but it's affecting my current version and the above would serve as a workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is untested, but you may want to try:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['caps:ctrl_modifier']"
```

Comment: For those who map Caps Lock to Escape, change `'caps:ctrl_modifier'` to  `'caps:escape'`. See this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/566871/how-to-map-the-caps-lock-key-to-escape-key-in-arch-linux) for more information.